# How to specify the content security policy in netbeans lightweight webserver?

Tags: javascript, html, netbeans, web, webserver

I am developing an html5 application on netbeans and I need to configure the netbeans lightweight web server to use a certain content security policy.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no way to anyhow configure the embedded lightweight server used in HTML5 applications. It is really lightweight :) You're gonna have to use some other server.